# Implementing SAML SSO session expiry on navigating back and forth between our system domains and external domains

Tags: reactjs, django, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, saml

My system uses django framework with MongoDB and reactJS. I have implemented SSO with the opensource python toolkit provided by OneLogin (https://pypi.org/project/python3-saml/)

Suppose we have a known set of our system domains ([www.app1.com](http://www.app1.com), [www.app2.com](http://www.app2.com)).
Am trying to implement session expiry when a user logs in with SSO in either of our known domains and navigates out to an external domain(like youtube etc.).

As long as the user switches between our known set of domains the existing session need not be invalidated.

I have currently integrated with Azure active directory as the Identity Provider(IDP).

When i login with SSO it redirects me to microsoft login and after successful login am redirected back to my backend server where i store the SAML token and redirect back to the frontend application domain.

The session data is getting stored under the microsoft domain in the browser and hence i have no access to that session data to clear it from the frontend when the user is  navigating out of my domain. And it doens't matter even if i delete the session data stored in my backend server since it is still present in the browser. It just takes that session from browser and sends it back to the backend.

Is there any way/links to invalidate the session or delete the session from the IDP without redirecting i.e, hitting the SLO url?

Am using the SLO url when the user is logging out and it redirects to the microsoft logout page again, but if the user is navigating out directly i can't hit the SLO url as it would just get cancelled since its a redirect.

Also assuming if i ever implement this session expiry on navigating out to external domain, how can i maintain the session if the user is only switching between out known set of domains. Is it possible to get the url to which the user is trying to navigte to during the 'beforeunload' event in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there's no way to remove the Azure AD browser session without hitting the [SLO endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-sign-out-saml-protocol).

Comment: is there any provision in AD to check if the current SAML session is active or not? Basically, a way to keep validating the session prior to every api access from the application.

Comment: another issue that am facing is on hitting SLO its not redirecting me back my application URL that am sending in the relayState/replyUrl param. it just stops at the microsoft logout page where it says "You should close the browser now...". although i can see my application url as a param in the url on this microsoft logout page.

Comment: Have you registered a Logout Url in your enterprise application SSO blade?